# VS Installer for both x32 and x64 files

Tags: x86, windows-installer, 64-bit, installation

I have two versions of program built in VS2010 (.net): for x86 and x64 Windows.

Then I try to put both variants in one installer so that it determines (using VersionNT64 condition or user dialog) what system it is ran on and depending on that it should install appropriate files.
Installer is set to target x86 platform, so it could be run on x86 system.

The problem is that VS gives an error when I try to put x64 file in x86 installer:
"ERROR: Module 'Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x64.msm' targeting 'x64' cannot be added to a package targeting 'x86'"
(Though x86 file in x64 installer is fine)

Is there a way to walk around this error? Is it possible to put x64 file in x86 installer? Or the only way is two installers for each system bitness?

Comment: terminology: "bit depth" applies to images and videos, where it's a measure of bits per color component.  There isn't really a proper term for the CPU context like you're using it here, although "bitness" is often used.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected that term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Short Answer***: If you don't need to target REAL x86 machines (as in real 32-bit hardware as opposed to newer 64-bit machines with x86 subsystems), then you can just set your package 64-bit and include x86 components. I think that should work.

---

***Technical Limitation***: A **`64-bit`** package can not install on a real **`x86`** machine, hence a package marked as **`x86`** can not contain **`64-bit`** components (or it could not install on its target platform). A **`x64`** MSI can install both **`x86`** components (32-bit) and **`x64`** components (64-bit) - they should target different installation paths. Here are some details: [Different Packages are Required for Different Processor Architectures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx) (Heath Stewart of Microsoft).

***Setup.exe Launcher***: I suppose you could deliver a single **`setup.exe`** containing two different MSI files: one for **`x86`** and one for **`x64`** and install the required one depending on target system? The **`setup.exe`** would have to be **`x86`** to be able to launch on **`x86`** machines. I don't do much of this at this point, most machines are 64-bit, so I use either x86 (installs on any machine) or x64 (installs on any 64-bit machine).

Comment: Thanks. That what I thought. "setup.exe containing two different MSI files" won't do the thing because setup.exe should be done x86 to be able to run on x86 machine and contain x64 msi for x64 machine - just as my example: x64 file in x86 package, error appears. Or is it something else?

Comment: The `setup.exe` would not be an MSI, so it should be able to contain a `64-bit` MSI and a `32-bit` MSI? In WiX you would use Burn to make a Bundle, in Installshield you would make a Suite project and in Advanced Installer you would perhaps use a chained package. Not sure of the details.

Comment: Advanced Installer has a dedicated mixed package type that cover this very scenario, but this is a paid feature. So if you are not looking for a free solution you can run a trial for Advanced Installer.